# delete row in table from firestore database

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a button to delete a row in my table from the firebase database but I am not sure how to choose one specific row to delete using a button function. I am using javascript and firesource.

The function that i am using to fill my table is

```
function filled_table_start(num){



document.getElementById("tbody1").innerHTML = "";

members.forEach((member) => {
if(member.exists()){
  
row += '<tr id="student'+ (count+1) +'" >';
row += '<td>' + (count+1) +'</td>';
row += '<td>' + member.data().studentID + '</td>';
row += '<td>' + member.data().name + '</td>';
row += '<td>' + member.data().gender + '</td>';
row += '<td>' + member.data().schoolEmailAdd + '</td>';
row += '<td>' + member.data().handphoneNum + '</td>';

row += '<td><button type="button" onclick= "' + deleteDoc(doc(db,this.studentID ))+'" >Delete User</td>';
//row += '<td>' + 

row += '</tr>';

document.getElementById('tbody1').innerHTML += row;
count ++;

};
});
}
```

I am wondering if something like this.deleteDoc will work? or is there another function that can be used to delete a specific row?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a dummy demo table here. What I did is, simply give a class to each of the buttons, when you will click on the button, It will find the [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) tr and remove it.

```js
$("#tbody1").on('click', '.deleteDoc', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="tbody1">
  <tr>
    <th>Sl</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Gender</th>
    <th>Mail</th>
    <th>Mobile</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
    <tr id="student1">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>abc@gmail.com</td>
      <td>123456</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="deleteDoc"> Delete User </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="student2">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>DEF</td>
      <td>M</td>
      <td>def@gmail.com</td>
      <td>123456</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="deleteDoc"> Delete User </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="student3">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>IJK</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>ijk@gmail.com</td>
      <td>123456</td>
      <td><button type="button" class="deleteDoc"> Delete User </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```